# TFS 2012 build exclude some project from compilation process

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have some strange behavior in my automatic build. When I open solution properties in build workspace I find that there is one project not checked in configuration to build, and my build fails. When I open this solution from TFS source control, this project is checked and build in VS pass successfully. Does anyone have an idea of what can exclude the project from solution configuration in build process?  Could there be any other reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check out if the project is included in the Configuration Manager window (solution context menu), for the given flavor (Release/Debug) and CPU. TFS build is probably using another configuration.